# ¿Como dejar fijo el tamaño de una ventana de dialogo QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Buenas, 
Estoy trabajando con la librería qt. Quisiera saber como desactivar el re dimensionamiento de una ventana de dialogo. Es decir fijar el **width y height** de la misma. Para que se entienda, no quiero maximizar o minimizar la ventana. Simplemente al pasar el cursor del **mouse** sobre los extremos de la ventana impedir que este activo el re dimensionamiento.

Existe algún tipo de opción o de que forma se debe implementar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones a elegir la que más te guste:

**opción 1:** [`QWidget::setFixedSize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize)

Estableces el tamaño a fijar y el widget (diálogo en este caso) queda fijado a dicho tamaño:

```
dialog->setFixedSize(dialog->sizeHint()); // posible opcion 1
dialog->setFixedSize(dialog->width(),dialog->height()); // posible opcion 2
```

**opción 2:** [`QLayout::setSizeConstraint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#sizeConstraint-prop)

En este caso atacas al layout principal del diálogo. Esta opción te permite bloquear el tamaño que tenga el diálogo en ese momento sin mayores complicaciones. Esta opción también es modificable vía el editor de formularios (QtCreator / QtDesigner)

```
dialog->layout()->setSizeConstraint( QLayout::SetFixedSize );
```

**opción 3:** Fijar tamaño máximo y mínimo del diálogo

La clase base `QWidget` dispone de los métodos [setMaximumSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#maximumSize-prop) y [setMinimumSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) que permiten fijar el tamaño máximo y mínimo del widget en cuestión.

Si ambos tamaños son iguales el resultado obtenido no permitirá modificar el tamaño del widget:

```
dialog->setMinimumSize(size());
dialog->setMaximumSize(size());
```